# Command line arguments not incrementinc argc

Tags: c++, command-line, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I am new to c++ and i am trying ti understand how it works .
So i have the next code :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
std::wcin.get();//for console window input
int i=1;
    // decode arguments
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("You must provide at least one argument\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    // report settings
    for (;i<argc;i++) printf("Argument %d:%s\n",i,argv[i]);

return 0;
}
```

for seeing how argc and argv works .
But no mater how many arguments i type in the console the argc won't increment.
It remains 1.
I know that argv[0] is the program name .My input is something like :"aaa bbb ccc ddd".
I belive for this argc should be 5 right ?
What am i doing wrong ? Why it will not increment ?

Thanks .

Comment: How are you passing those args to your program?

Comment: From the console window ,when it pops up from wcin.get(); I enter the arguments ,like "abc efg xyz" .

Comment: @IonutDaniel when the console of the program opens, the command line arguments are already set. It's too late by then.

Comment: @Ionut that's the problem, arguments aren't passed like that. See the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're using MSVS (signature being `_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`). If you're running the code from the IDE, you'll need to specify the arguments in the project settings, not the command line.

[image]

Running from the command line like:

```
test.exe arg1 arg2
```

will also work correctly. What you're doing doesn't modify the arguments.

Comment: Hey ,thanks now it works .This was very usefull .I have another question in this case . I am doing this "research" in order ti create an command line parser where the arguments will be passed as : -switch1 argument1 argument2 -switch2 argument and so on .Could i use this setting in this case ?

Comment: @IonutDaniel this setting only works when you run the program from visual studio. If you plan on running the executable manually, you'll have to use the command line option.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little .This matter it is a little abstract to me . Thanks again .

Comment: @IonutDaniel if you tell me which setting you're referring to, yes.

Comment: I am referring at the use of the command line option .How can i read the arguments from the console window before the argument are set, in order to parse the input.

Comment: @IonutDaniel How could you read any arguments before they are set?

Comment: @IonutDaniel also, the second part of my answer deals with starting the application with the arguments - `test.exe argument1 argument2`. Then, when the code is running, you don't need to call anything, `argc` and `argv` will already contain that info. There's no need for `std::wcin.get();`.

Answer (score 2):

Calling wcin.get() does not affect argv or argc.  The arguments are specified at the very beginning when the program is launched.  They are specified on the command line, right after the program name, separated by spaces.